# True or false in logic and entailment sound

Tags: logic

> Are these T/F? **Refer** to soundness/completeness if needed. (ND system)
>
> (A) If $a, b \vDash d$ and $c$ is any formula then $a, b, c, \vDash d$?

I say **true.** By completelness we see $a, b \vdash d$, we attach $c$ to get $a, b, c \vdash d$, which is true because we can ignore $c$ to use the $a, b$ origin premise. Then by soundness we witness $a, b, c \vDash d$. Correct?

> (B) If $a \vDash b$ does not hold, then $\vdash \neg (a \implies b)$

I see the valuation of $\vDash \neg(a \implies b)$. This isnt a tautology so $\vDash \neg(a \implies b)$ does **not** hold. By the contrapositive of soundness theorem, $\vdash \neg (a \implies b)$ does not hold. Correct?

> (C) If $a \vDash b$ and $\neg a \vDash \neg b$ then $\vDash \neg b$.

Since $\neg b$ is not a tautology, this doesnt hold?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$\vdash \varphi$ means that $\varphi$ can be inferred from no premises at all.

$\vDash \varphi$ means that for every valuation $v: v(\varphi)= True$

So, for example, you have $\vDash P \lor \neg P$. Indeed, we have $\vDash \varphi$ if and only if $\varphi$ is a tautology. And if your proof system is complete, then we have $\vdash \varphi$ whenever $\vDash \varphi$

Now, your proof for part (A) works, though you can also just talk about $\vDash$ without talking about $\vdash$: If $a,b\vDash d$ then any valuation $v$ that sets $a$ and $b$ to $True$ will have to set $d$ to $True$ as well. From this, it immediately folows that any valuation that sets $a$, $b$, and $c$ to $True$ will set $d$ to $True$ as well. Hence, $a,b,c \vDash d$.

For (B) and (C) you need to use the givens, because you should treat $a$ and $b$ as arbitrary formulas.

Comment: Oh I see. For the first part is my answer correct? I'll add them in for the other parts

Comment: Your proof for part (A) works, though you can also just talk about $\vDash$ without talking about $\vdash$:  If $a,b \vDash d$ then every truth-assignment $h$ that sets $a$ and $b$ to $True$ will have to set $d$ to $True$ as well. From this, it immediately folows that any truth-assignment that sets $a$, $b$, and $c$ to $True$ will set $d$ to $True$ as well. Hence, $a,b,c \vDash d$.

Comment: Ok, what about for part (B)?

Comment: @Marodian You need to use the given that $a \vDash b$ does not hold, for if $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary formulas, then $a$ could both be $P$, in which case $\not \vdash \neg (a \rightarrow b)$. Same goes for (C): you need to treat $a$ and $b$ as arbitrary sentences, so you cannot immediately say that $\neg b$ is not a tautology. Again, you need to use the givens.

Comment: Why isnt the tautology argument correct?

Comment: Oh yeah, I see why that argument isnt correct. I dont see what you mean by $a$ could both be $P$?

Comment: @Marodian You need to think of $a$ and $b$ as sentence variables, like $\phi$ or $\psi$. Granted, the question would have been phrased better had they used those variables, but I am sure that that is what they mean. Otherwise, you would indeed not even have to use the givens ... but no text or instructor is ever going to do something like that.